# Unexpected behavior of in_array in closure for filter_var

Tags: php

I wrote a function that, when used as `FILTER_CALLBACK` in `filter_var`, is meant to validate that a value is part of an allowed set:

```php
function is_one_of() {
    $allowed_values = func_get_args();
    return function($value) use ($allowed_values) {
        return in_array($value, $allowed_values, true);
    };
}
```

But it gives me unexpected results:

```php
var_dump( filter_var('6', FILTER_CALLBACK, ['options' => is_one_of('6')]) );
#=> bool(true)  // OK

var_dump( filter_var('6', FILTER_CALLBACK, ['options' => is_one_of( 6 )]) );
#=> bool(false) // OK

var_dump( filter_var( 6 , FILTER_CALLBACK, ['options' => is_one_of('6')]) );
#=> bool(true)  // FAIL

var_dump( filter_var( 6 , FILTER_CALLBACK, ['options' => is_one_of( 6 )]) );
#=> bool(false) // FAIL
```

What's happening?

Comment: From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/function.filter-var.php)... _"Note that scalar values are converted to string internally before they are filtered."_

Comment: Thanks Phil, that explains the observed behavior; If you post it as an answer I'll accept it. **Aside:** So a partial workaround would be to cast the allowed values to strings with `$allowed_values = array_map('strval', func_get_args());` ?

Comment: This seems like a bit of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). How are you even acquiring variables that require filtering as anything but a string? The kinds of things you filter come from unknown sources and I just can't see how those would be strictly numeric types

Comment: @Phil The variables to be filtered should always be strings, but the list of allowed values might be written as literal numbers in the code, for convenience.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Your `strval` idea should work but why not simply remove the strict check for `in_array()`?

Comment: @Phil If I remove the strict then I'd still need to convert the allowed values to strings, or else `filter_var( '', FILTER_CALLBACK, ['options' => is_one_of(0)]);` would return `true`

Comment: You make an excellent point. I think you should post your strval answer below

Answer (score 0):

```php
function is_one_of(...$allowed_values): callable {
    return static function($value) use ($allowed_values): bool {
        foreach ($allowed_values as $allowed_value) {
            if (strcmp($allowed_value, $value) === 0) {
               return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    };
}
```

https://onlinephp.io/c/61851

Comment: I tested it on php-7.3 and `filter_var('', FILTER_CALLBACK, ['options' => is_one_of(0)])` still returns `true`; thanks nevertheless, adding the `static` might improve the performance of numerous calls.

Comment: `7.3.33, 7.3.0` returns false

https://onlinephp.io?s=rZFPa8JAEMXvgt9hDoHdBQmeclBjsdJCaU6ltyLLGmdxYZsN-8cexO_epFqIiUgCvts-5v2YN7t4KvfleCRDkXtlClCOmwK5kTSO40hobX5wxw9CB3RsBnnliK1GOI5H0JBFH2wBzguvcvin0egvyCA4BNqlbY3RbVItaSyKfN-JgHBwbbFb8VpKttOQphDdDzWaeBtwfnvq1LUrq2teSFJo10adGu-r7EFYvgvfJZVKe7TV5paShEzg9S37fPng61WWPa_W7xP4Iqasb-wIpMvGt1XTbMPY_JHMpAcxefiOQ4h9NiRDKk97AKdDKp8b_wI%2C&v=7.3.33%2C7.3.0

Comment: In the online demo, the result of the var_dump at line 18 is `true`

Comment: Look at update.